# Question about Binary classification Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm studying classification system using keras.
Keras classify labels by checking which is the highest number.
For instance, if output is [0.1 0.8 0.1], it classify label 1 as correct answer because it is 0.8 which is highest number.

But in binary classification I got this result.

```
[0.642]
[0.996]
[0.976]
[0.302]
[0.963]
[0.115]
   .
   .
   .
```

I thought Keras classify them as:
if result[i][0] > 0.5 return 1

But it is only my guess so I want to know exactly how Keras classify binary results.

Here is my code I used.

```
model = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
model.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

import numpy as np

print("-- Predict --")
output = model.predict_generator(test_set, steps=5)
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: "{0:0.3f}".format(x)})
print(test_set.class_indices)
print(output)
```

Comment: What is your model and your optimization objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, we can see `model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))`.
So we are using `sigmoid` as activation function.
if you see [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/m4auBFX8TiS7By2TA) link, you will see that range of function is [0,1] so considering threshold as 0.5, classes are assigned.

if you would have been doing multi-class classification, softmax will be the appropriate activation function.

Comment: thank you for your reply :) it really helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to learn various activation function. In the given exmaple, you are using sigmoid activation function which outputs a continous range of values between 0 and 1. If you use softmax function , it will generate outputs a vector that represents the probability distributions of a list of potential outcomes. it will turns numbers aka logits into probabilities that sum to one [0.1 0.8 0.1] like you mentioned in your question.

Comment: thank you for your reply :) I'm gonna study about activation functions